# PKCS7 encrypt decrypt in Node.js

Tags: node.js, openssl, pkcs#7

I am using pkcs7 encrypt decrypt in current project. I want to change from PHP to Node.js. Is there pkcs7 encrypt/decrypt in Node.js ?

In PHP,

```
<?php

$data = <<<EOD
Hello world
EOD;

// load key
$key = file_get_contents("mypublickey.crt");

// save message to file
$fp = fopen("msg.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

// encrypt it
if (openssl_pkcs7_encrypt("msg.txt", "enc.txt", $key,array())) {
    // message encrypted - send it!

}
?>
```

to decrypt

```
<?php
// The certification stuff
$public = file_get_contents("mypublickey.crt");
$private = array(file_get_contents("myprivatekey.pem"), "mypassword");

$infile = tempnam("", "enc");
file_put_contents($infile, $encrypted); 
$outfile = tempnam("", "dec");

if(openssl_pkcs7_decrypt("enc.txt", "dec.txt", $public, $private))
{
    // Decryption successful
    echo file_get_contents("dec.txt");
}
?>
```

Is there any similar function like this in Node.js ?

Comment: Thanks for the concise example of pkcs7 encryption in PHP :)

Comment: Hey! did you find any way to implement in Node.js?

Comment: no luck. that why used php for project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've faced the same issue and spent too much time but I found a way in the end.

I found and used [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) open source lib. You can simply add to your project by following:

```
npm install node-forge
```

Then, code snippet below performs encryption with `PKCS#7` format.

```
var forge = require('node-forge');

// create cert object
var cert = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(certOrPemString);
// create envelop data
var p7 = forge.pkcs7.createEnvelopedData();
// add certificate as recipient
p7.addRecipient(cert);
// set content 
p7.content = forge.util.createBuffer();
p7.content.putString('content to be encrypted');

// encrypt
p7.encrypt();

// obtain encrypted data with DER format
var bytes = forge.asn1.toDer(p7.toAsn1()).getBytes();
```

This code block will encrypt the content you provided and return a byte array with `DER` output format.

You can convert byte array to `UTF-8` string by following:

```
var str = Buffer.from(bytes, 'binary').toString('utf8');
```

And you can decrypt the content as follows:

```
var recipient = p7.findRecipient(cert);
// decrypt
p7.decrypt(p7.recipients[0], privateKey);
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: how about decrypt ?

Comment: @saturngod please look at [this](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#pkcs7) section. There's a `decrypt()` method provided.

Comment: couldn't load private key. Now, I get same pkcs7 encrypted base64 like `var pem = forge.pkcs7.messageToPem(p7);` . However, cannot decrypt yet.

Comment: PKI.privateKeyFromPem(privateKey); is not working because of encrypted. I don't know how to put password for private key.

Comment: @saturngod were you able to decrypt the message in node.js eventually?

Comment: @ThanakritWeekhamchai yes. can decrypt, too.

Comment: @saturngod how can we decrypt with a password? Thank you!

Comment: We've a PKCS7 encrypted message coming on the server side. We used openssl_pkcs7_decrypt() function in PHP to decrypt it till now. However, we are converting this PHP application to NodeJS now and struggling to find good examples for it. Not sure how could I use the above code snippet to supply encrypted (which is not part of the same class) message and get the decrypted message.

Answer (score 3):

To Decrypt Data

Example Data:

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

```
        let data = '-----BEGIN PKCS7-----\r\n' + body + '\r\n-----END PKCS7-----\r\n';
        let p7d = forge.pkcs7.messageFromPem(data)
        let privateCert = forge.pki.decryptRsaPrivateKey(fs.readFileSync(privateCertPath),'password');
        p7d.decrypt(p7d.recipients[0], privateCert);
        console.log(p7d.content)
```